# Does Titanium Backup work with system using Link2SD

Tags: backup, link2sd, titanium-backup

[Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) is a root app that allows you to back up your apps and all their data.

[Link2SD](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) is a root app that moves all files an app stores in internal storage to a special partition on SD card, and creates symlinks into the internal storage in place of the original files.

**Does Titanium Backup work with Link2SD?** That is, does it correctly back up the files that the symlinks point to, or does it instead end up backing up just the symlinks?

Comment: I don't know about Titanium Backup but I can tell you that My Backup Pro didn't work with Link2SD. It backed up data perfectly, but not apps APKs.

Comment: It works, but can't tell the difference between an app installed on the phone's memory and an app that's been linked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Titanium Backup works fine with Link2SD. I've been using them together for about six months, with around 100 apps symlinked. There's no reason taking a backup would uninstall linked apps as Wolfgang reports, and I've also had zero issues restoring backups of linked apps, so it's clear that Titanium follows the symlinks correctly. In fact, I have just finished restoring all my apps from Titanium after flashing a ROM.

**The only caveat** is that when you restore in Titanium, Link2SD will not automatically link apps as they are restored, even if you set it up before restoring the rest of your apps. This is annoying, because it means you have to be conscious of your available internal memory and only restore in batches that will fit in your free space, then link the apps and do another batch.

Other than that, they work very smoothly alongside each other.

Comment: However, if you have the free version of Titanium Backup, the way it batch restores apps is different. It basically installs each app individually, requiring you to click 'install' each time. Because of this, link2sd actually works better because it is getting the `app installed` intent.

Comment: this is actually not true for me. even though i have to click 3 times for each app restore, it restores them all to internal storage. auto link in link2sd is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it works, but only in the same terminal.

If you move your sdcard with a titanium backup done previously from a terminal with android 2.3.6 to another terminal with android 4.2, the titanium backup will detect the backup done before, but it can't restore anything of it.
Perhaps if you install link2sd in a android 4.2, can you do it?